# Using the field of view as zooming solution (in 3D with XNA) stretches models vertically

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, zooming

So I am learning to use 3D with XNA in order to use in my next project. I need to have a method of zooming in/out. After searching, I have found that changing the field of view is quite a satisfying method.

However, the problem I'm running into is that, at high FOVs (quite zoomed out), the model is stretched vertically way more that I can tolerate. If this helps, my camera is above the model (top-down view).

So, how do I fix the stretching? If this is a side-effect of the FOV, what other zooming solutions are there?

Comment: Change the cameras position instead of the fov

Comment: @Sayse I've tried, but then (even with a large far clipping plane distance) the model disappears way too early. EDIT: And what I'd like is completely reasonable)

Comment: Can you add your Camera projection and view declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Field of View as zooming solution is not appropiate...

You should modify the view transform of your camera with Matrix.CreateLookAt

if your projectinon is perspective:

```
      Target = What_you_want...=> Model.Position; 
      Camera.Position = Target - Camera.Forward * Zoom;
      Camera.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt( Camera.Position, Target, Camera.Up);
```

if your projection is orthographic:

```
      Target = What_you_want...=> Model.Position; 
      Camera.Position = Target - Camera.Forward;
      Camera.View =  Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom) 
                   * Matrix.CreateLookAt( Camera.Position, Target, Camera.Up);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I explained it above too, but (no matter where the far clipping plane was), the model would get clipped out at about 4x zoomed out.

Comment: Scale your model to make it smaller... and ensure that is not clipped by 'near' plane

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to zoom the FOV:

```
   Camera.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(2f * Math.Atan(Math.Tan(Camera.FieldofView / 2f) / CalculateYAspect(Camera.AspectRatio, 16f / 9f, 0) / Camera.ZoomFactor), Camera.AspectRatio, Camera.NearPlane, Camera.FarPlane)

   public float CalculateYAspect(float AspectRatio, float ConditionalAspect, int AspectAxisConstraint)
   {
       switch(AspectAxisConstraint)
       {
          default:
             if (AspectRatio < ConditionalAspect)
             {
                goto case 2
             }
             else
             {
                goto case 1
             }
          case 1:
             return ConditionalAspect / ConditionalAspect
          case 2:
             return AspectRatio / ConditionalAspect
       }
   }
```